# Looking for the exact number of iterations

Tags: c, iteration

In `Fa(x, a)`, **x** is some number and **a** is number of iterations.
Furthermore, in `Fb(x, y, dev)`, **min** and **max** is a lower and upper interval and **dev** some allowed deviation, which returns the needed number of iterations for each number in the interval. E.g., if 5 iterations are needed for **min** and 10 iterations for **max**, `Fb` returns 10.

Thus, this yields:

```
unsigned int Fa(double x, unsigned int a);

unsigned int Fb(double min, double max, double dev)  {
  unsigned int it_min = 1;
  unsigned int it_max = 1;
  for(; fabs(Fa(min, it_min) - Fa(min, it_min+1)) > dev; it_min++);
  for(; fabs(Fa(max, it_max) - Fa(max, it_max+1)) > dev; it_max++);
  return it_min > it_max ? it_min+1 : it_max+1;
}
```

However, this kind of function is really slow for large numbers (> 1000) where number of iterations are insane (iterations > 100,000,000).
Is there faster way?

I made it faster by adding `it_min* = 20`, with a for loop using `it_min--`, but its still too slow.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: By what comparable measures do you know that your algorithm is too slow?

Comment: You might want to examine some of the properties of `Fa()`, and see if you can change the loop to exploit those properties.

Comment: @gustafbstrom - lets say, if input <1e-4 AND input>1e4, it takes 1 - 5 seconds. But when I need to find result for input <1e-10 or less it can take more than 10 minutes... Or what do you mean with your question? I think I dont understand what do you mean.

Comment: @Peter Yes, thats good point too, I will take closer look. Thanks

Comment: @Tehryn What I mean is that the problem you want to solve might very well have non-linear complexity, i.e. O(n^2) or larger. If so, increasing the input the way you describe might really have an expected effect on the runtime time. Why I ask because `Fa` is unknown in your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer: I expect input numbers `<1e-5 AND numbers>1e5`, so I start with a huge number of iterations: `(INT_MAX/2)`. Then, I check in which interval the result is found and then divide it again. This will be repeated until I get correct result.

Comment: If this fixed your problem, you should probably mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an optimization:

```
unsigned int iter(double v, double dev, unsigned int i) {
  double r;
  double fa1 = Fa(min, i);
  do {
    double fa2 = Fa(min, ++i)
    r = fabs(fa1-fa2);
    fa1 = fa2;
  } while (r > dev);
  return i;
}

unsigned int Fb(double min, double max, double dev)  {
  unsigned int it_min = iter(min, dev, 1);
  unsigned int it_max = iter(max, dev, 1);

  return it_min > it_max ? it_min+1 : it_max+1;
}
```

This way, you will evaluate `Fa` only *once* each iteration, instead of twice.

Comment: well, this is really usefull, but its not still enought. I have an idea, to make interval of iterations, from 0 to UINT_MAX-1 and than cut this interval to half and check in which half of interval is result and that cut it again and again if you understand me... But then I will have problems to find result for "common" numbers like 0.5 or 5... This will only help for really huge or really small numbers. I hope you know, what I mean... My explenation skills are really low, sorry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You perform duplicate calls to Fa. Here is a way to eliminate these duplicates. The response time will decrease by half:

```
unsigned int Fb(double min, double max, double dev)  {
  unsigned int it_min = 0;
  unsigned int it_max = 0;

  double delta;
  double previousFa = Fa(min, 1);
  do {
    it_min++;
    double nextFa = Fa(min, it_min+1);
    delta = previousFa - nextFa;
    previousFa = nextFa;
  } while (delta > dev);

  ... // do the same for max/it_max

  return it_min > it_max ? it_min+1 : it_max+1;
}
```